# How to put terminal commands into a file and run it

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal

I'm somewhat new to Ubuntu so I apologize for my lack of knowledge on the subject.

*Is it possible to put terminal commands into a file in Ubuntu 16.04 and then run that file and have those commands be executed?*

For example.
If I have a file named 'somefile'

And in that file I have:

`cd Desktop`

```
chmod + x top.sh
```

`top -n 1 -b > top-somefilename.txt`

In the terminal can I run that file and have those commands be executed?
If so how do I do it?

Comment: Like that: `./top.sh`

Comment: thank you, that was the answer to my question.  I'm unclear why this was downvoted though.  
@syntagma Please post your comment below as an answer so I can give you points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell cripts that are in the current folder are executed in the following way (with a `./` at the beginning):

`./top.sh`